# How to import contacts, which are in excel format to Blackberry device(may be in bbb format)

Tags: blackberry

I have contacts in Excel file, I want to import these contacts to BlackBerry Bold device.
I have used Contacts to Excel s/w to do the same, but I am not getting proper output.

Comment: If it is an end-user request and you are looking for a software solution, then please post your question on superuser.com But if you are asking for a solution from programmer's point of view, please state it in your question and note what you have tried to code.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelOsipov, it's end-user questions.. I found the answer as below.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Synch contacts(Import / Export) (to and From) Outlook as below.

1. Prepare your Excel file of contacts.
2. convert Excel file(xls) to csv file.
3. Map the Header of csv file to the fields available in the Outlook.
4. From File menu choose Import / Export Option.
5. Go with 
    Import from another program or file
    Export to a file
6. Choose comma Separate Values(Windows).
7. Select Destination / Source to Import / Export csv file.
8. Now Open **Blackberry Desktop Software**
9. Select Organizer
    Choose your IN - OUT flow of Data 
    Choose your filed mapping through configuration.
    You also can change source / destination field mapping through configuration.
10. Select the checkbox near by your precess.
11. Hit Sync Organizer.

That's it. You are done with your synchronization.

Note: Be aware while following step 9.